# Using Visual Studio Developer Prompt for target execution

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I have VS2017 installed and a target file I have a target file

```
<Target Name="TargetName">
      <Exec Command="some-command"></Exec>
</Target>
```

Target command runs fine. Except it run in cmd instead of developer command prompt. Previously, it used to run in developer command prompt.

I know this because it is not able to find variable VCINSTALLDIR and also nmake command. When I run the same command from developer prompt, they work as expected.

I have reinstalled VS2017. Still the issue persists. Is there any setting in VS2017 to make it use developer prompt?

Comment: That is not accurate.  Replace the command with "cmd.exe /c set path" to diagnose differences.

Comment: @HansPassant I did what you asked. it printed system environments path. What is not accurate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by adding vsdevcmd.bat in the PATH environment and changing command to

```
<Exec Command="call vsdevcmd.bat &amp; some-command"></Exec>
```